# The webpage at (website) might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis

I have developped a wcf web service in VS2010. The web service works good in VS2010, added the web service reference to a project (winform) in the same solution, everything works great, call of methods, good.

When I deploy my web service I get :

```
The webpage at (website) might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

I'm new to WCF web services, what do I need to deploy to make it work correctly?

I deployed the .svc file and web.config.
I deployed all .dll files in the bin directory.

I check my project folder, there is aa Web.config, Web.Release.config and Web.Debug.config.

Do I need to deploy Web.Release.config? But there is not much of a content in it :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

     <system.web>
        <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
     </system.web>

</configuration>
```

In my Web.config I have the appsettings, bindings, services and all, do I need to copy all the stuff in my Web.Release.config file?

Any solution/suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an issue with WCF but rather with IIS. Additionally, it sounds like when you say 'deploy' you mean copying the build output results to the target directory. You'd be better off using Publish from the project right-click menu. Are you familiar with how to configure IIS?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie not much, I read WCF need to be installed on the IIS server, may that be the problem?

Comment: Correct. You will need to setup the IIS application, directory, app-pool, etc., and then place your published code in the folder to which that application points. What Windows version are you using to host?  I'll try to get some relevant screen shots.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie I'll be testing it on a new server running Windows 2012, any screen shots is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To host your WCF project (or anything in IIS, for that matter), it would be worth a read over [Hosting in Internet Information Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734710.aspx). You can deploy your project by following the directions at [WCF Service Publishing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924407.aspx).

For an example solution, lets assume you are using a machine with IIS 7. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager under Administrator Tools.

First we will choose or create an Application Pool for our application to use. It can use an existing Application Pool as long as it uses the same .NET version, or you can create a new one. You will likely have something similar to:

[image: IIS_AppPool]

Next, you will choose a Site to host your WCF service. You can use an existing site or create a new site. I am going to just use Default Web Site, and will Add Application...

[image: IIS_AddApplication]

This physical path will be where you deploy your WCF project. Say that your host machine is named MyHostMachine. To deploy your WCF, right-click your project, select Publish...
In that popup, select Publish method of Web Deploy, set the Service URL (ex: `http://MyHostMachine`), and Site/application (ex: `Default Web Site/MyWcfService`).

Note: If you have any permission issues that prevent you from doing a Web Deploy, then you can simply deploy to somewhere in the local File System, and copy the full contents from there to the application directory on your host machine.

Comment: Glad I could help. One more recommendation I would make, @ThePig'sEar , is you might try using the `Use IIS Express...` option under the WCF project right-click menu (available in VS2010 SP1 or as separate add-on). IIS Express should closer resemble the 2012 IIS environment than the built-in WebDev server of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In MyCase it's just changing `applicationURL` value from `https://localhost:portNumber` to `http://localhost:portNumber` in **Application** > **profiles** > **webapplication** > `launchSettings.json` .It got worked.